# Calling a Javascript function with an unknown number of arguments with original context

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm currently using Function.apply to call a function with a dynamic number of arguments, but I do not have access to the original context, and have no desire to set the context myself. What I would like, is to be able to call a function with a variable number of arguments, keeping the original context.

Perhaps some code should show you what I'm trying to do:

```
function MulticastDelegate() {
    var handlers = [];

    this.event = {
        subscribe: function(handler) {
            if (typeof(handler) === 'function') {
                handlers.push(handler);
            }
        },
        unsubscribe: function(handler) {
            if (typeof(handler) === 'function') {
                handlers.splice(handlers.indexOf(handler),1);
            }
        }
    }

    this.execute = function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        for (var handler in handlers) {
            // call this with the original context of the handler
            handlers[handler].apply(null, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want the behaviour of `apply` - the ability to pass an array of arguments - without the behaviour of `call` - changing the context under which a function executes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as “the original context” of a function. You would have to do something like this:

```
subscribe: function(handler, context) {
    if (typeof(handler) === 'function') {
        handlers.push([handler, context]);
    }
},
```

And then, of course,

```
handlers[handler][0].apply(handlers[handler][1], args);
```

Alternatively (this is what I would do), leave it to the caller to make sure the handler has the right context. For example, instead of `delegate.subscribe(this.foo)`, say

```
var self = this
delegate.subscribe(function () { self.foo() })
```

Or, using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind),

```
delegate.subscribe(this.foo.bind(this))
```

Comment: I think what you describe here is exactly what Backbone.js does in its event binding framework: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-12

Comment: I think you're right about letting the caller take care of the context under which it is executed, by using the `var self` method or something similar. Then I can provide a more appropriate object for `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that `.bind` would solve the case?
       http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind
In this case, you get a function 'binded' to the original context